# How to check if brew installs M1 or intel packages?

Tags: macos, homebrew, apple-silicon

I have installed JetBrains Toolbox using

`brew install --cask jetbrains-toolbox`.

I am experiencing quite a lag when scrolling and overall slow interface while using `WebStorm, IntelliJ` and `PyCharm`.

I suspect that it might be due to running `Intel-based` apps over Rosetta, How can I check?

PS: This is my first post here, please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Where is brew installed?

Comment: I just checked using  `which brew`,  It is  installed at  `/opt/homebrew/bin/brew`.

Comment: Assuming you didn‘t mess around with the default installation, this is the M1 version. You can run `file` on the Webstorm binary to check though.

Comment: Rosetta doesn‘t have a runtime effect on performance, an Intel binary get compiled into ARM code the first time you run it. If you see lag, the reason must be something else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @nohillside, I'll try o look somewhere else in that case.

Comment: At a guess you are suffering from a tradeoff between performance and cross OS compatibility.  There is a lot of Java/JVM/JavaScipt in those apps. Is the Java etc. code Apple silicon or Intel?

Comment: @nohillside These IDEs use Java/JVM/JavaScript, etc. So there are multiple layers of software here. How they interact with Rosetta may not be that simple.

Comment: Have you tried using the downloads from JetBrains? I see that you can choose a specific installer for Intel or Apple silicon. https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/

Comment: @gilby Rosetta is not an emulator, any binary gets converted before it runs. Also, Java code runs within the Java runtime and is not platform specific.